# Can't install new Seagate HD on mac -- greyed partion option under disk utilites

Tags: mac, hdd

On my mac, trying to set up new Seagate Expansion Portable Drive. I get to the Disk utility, but the partition option is greyed out.

Comment: Can you please give us more details? What kind of computer? Which operating system? Can you take a picture or screenshot of the disk utility page where you're having problems?

Comment: ... & Bearing in mind it's likely to be MBR/NTFS when you get it, did you first try to reformat the entire drive as GUID/HFS+ before partitioning?

Comment: Also, can you please add a screenshot showing Disk Utility?

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood, the drive is formatted as NTFS - Window’s proprietary filesystem - which operates as *read only* in OS X. In order to partition the drive, or even use it, you need to reformat it first.

- Open Disk Utility. Select the hard drive from the sidebar. Click “Erase”
- Choose a name for the volume. You must also choose a format and scheme. The default OS X configuration is HFS+ Journaled with a GUID partition map. Unless you require universal compatibility, just go with that format.
- Click erase
- Now you’ll be able to partition/modify the drive to your liking.